# Is there a way to know default TabLayout height from XML

Tags: android

We can know action bar / toolbar height from XML, via `?attr/actionBarSize`

Is there a similar thingy for `TabLayout` height? Something like `?attr/tabLayoutSize`

Comment: I think you mean "assign the height with XML" instead of "know the height from XML"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, NO.

But the google design specs says that it the height of tabs should be `48dp` or `72dp` in case of icon + text in a tab

https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/tabs.html#tabs-specs

Comment: Welcome to android support library where we build components that don't respect our own specifications ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score -1):

A bit code would be helpful. 
You can set the hight of the tablayout in xml like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/tablayout_height"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="10dp"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/blue"
    style="@style/TabStyle"/>
```

And if you for example want to get that height in your code you could get it by doing this:

int height = (int) mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.tablayout_height);

Comment: That's not what he is asking